# Trying to handle an error but cannot do it! Telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I have made a telegram bot using pyrogram to upload a large video and the the progress bar is shown, however the progress bar is repeatedly edited message with new values.

This error message is shown frequently:

```
Waiting for 3 seconds before continuing (required by "messages.EditMessage")
```

I am trying to skip this error by try except block

```
try:
    await msg.edit(text=current_message)
except:
    pass
```

but this is not working, the error message still shows up!

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get is Pyrogram handling the FloodWait error from Telegram itself. You can set the `sleep_threshold` when defining `Client()` to `0`, so you get the actual error you can `except` yourself. Pyrogram will automatically re-try, whereas you would have to re-implement that again, if you don't want something to go missing in-between.

Alternatively, don't update your Progress Bar as quickly, and increase your increment size. Instead of updating on every single 1% progress, do something like

```py
if progress % 5 == 0:
    msg.edit("Progress: {}", format=progress)
```

This if statement calculates the modulo of your progress, and only updates when it is cleanly divisible by 5. The `%` operator returns the remainder when dividing your  progress.

Also; Pyrograms Documentation about Errors: https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/errors/

Comment: After adding if statement, the process altogether stops working, lol! It is stuck!